# BCP command in Linux doesn't return the proper error code

Tags: sql-server, bcp

In Linux/Unix based systems, whenever we execute a command in the shell and we echo the `$?`, the return value is 0 when its a success and the return value is 1 if the command fails.

So, if I am using the BULK COPY utility called BCP for SQL Server, and if the command fails when there is an error with the source file. For example, if I execute a bcp command like this.
`/opt/bin/bcp <tablename> in <source_file> -S -U -P -D`
and it says. "**0 Rows Copied**". It might be due to some errors in the source file. And, after that I do a `echo $?`. The value returned is still 0.

Is there a way we can capture the return value as 1, when encountered an error?

Thanks.

Comment: The first sentence of the second alinea doesn't make any sense.

Comment: There is an error with the source file, or even there might be some error at the SQL Server level. Like if the mentioned table doesn't exist. The BCP command still returns the value 0 at the ```$?```, which should be 1 as is in the case of other commands in Unix.

Comment: Have you verified whether or not there *is* an error? `0 rows copied` might also mean that `bcp` considers the source to contain no records (which is not an error, even if it is not what you expect). Double check with something blatantly invalid, like an incorrect path.

Comment: On Windows, I can confirm `bcp` *will* have a non-zero exit status if an actual error occurs (like invoking with incorrect parameters, or a database error) -- verified with PowerShell and `$lastexitcode`. If you just want to verify that rows were actually copied, you'll probably need to check for a zero exit code and verify that "0 rows copied" is not part of the output. If it won't return a non-zero exit code even for database errors, that's a bug. (I'm not sure where you go to report it to have it fixed these days, though.)

Answer (score 0):

BCP doesn't [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) any return value. That's a shortcoming. What you can do is redirect output to a file, and look for error indications (probably, the text "Error").

Answer (score 0):

To add a bit more detail to TT.'s answer, I write the bcp output to another file and then grep through it. My code looks like...

```sh
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp "$TABLENAME" in $f \
                -S $DEST_IP \
                -U $USER -P $PASSWORD \
                -d $DEST_DB \
                -c \
                -t "\t" \
                -e $EXPORT_STAGE/$TABLENAME/$TABLENAME.$(basename $f).bcperror.log \
                | tee $EXPORT_STAGE/$TABLENAME/$TABLENAME.$(basename $f).bcprun.log
                # note here that I preserve the bcp output to can later in script

# look for error messages in the bcp process run itself (manually done since bcp does not throw error codes)
echo -e "\n Checking for error messages in bcp output\n"
if grep -q "Error" $EXPORT_STAGE/$TABLENAME/$TABLENAME.$(basename $f).bcprun.log
    then
        echo -e "\n\nError: error message detected in bcp process output, exiting..."
        exit 255
    fi
# can delete since already printing to stdout as well (and can just log the whole thing)
rm -f $EXPORT_STAGE/$TABLENAME/$TABLENAME.$(basename $f).bcprun.log
```